# File `libertine.sty` not found (package latexila)

Tags: fonts, libertine

I recently installed tex-live full in ubuntu 14.
I am working in latexila.
When compiling a `.tex` file, the following error occurs:

```
File `libertine.sty' not found.
```

What can I do to compile the document?

Comment: `latexila` is an editor; it probably does not have anything to do with the package. Are you sure, the package `libertine` is contained in tex-live?

Comment: What does `pdflatex --version` yield?

Comment: pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.0
Copyright 2014 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.6.10; using libpng 1.6.10
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with poppler version 0.26.2

Comment: Welcome! Are you using `pdflatex` to compile? What does `kpsewhich libertine.sty` give? Probably that package is part of another `tex-live` package which you need to install with your package manager, just as you installed `tex-live full`. But we really need a bit more information to say for sure.

Comment: @Scz right, the problem might come from the package libertine, I've read that it's contained in tex-live. 
Am auto-removing tex-live and reinstalling it,
I'll tell you the result !
Thanks

Comment: after reinstalling tex-live full \\
kpsewhich libertine.sty gives /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/libertine/libertine.sty 
And the compilation works finally 
Thanks everyone.

Comment: Since the problem was solved by reinstalling the software, I'm voting to close.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue has been solved by a software update